# Round values with 2 decimal places and add 0 if not decimal are present

Tags: javascript

How I can round a value maintaining 2 decimal places? I have tried using `Math.round(val)` but doesn't work.

Takes these numbers as examples:

- `25` should be converted to `25.00`
- `25.3666` should be rounded to `25.37`
- `25.55333` should be rounded to `25.55`

Comment: Use .toFixed(2); --- like parseFloat("123.456789").toFixed(2);

Comment: var m = parseFloat(fullamount).toFixed(2);  Its working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at `toFixed()`.

```
var a = 2;
a = a.toFixed(2);
```

now a is 2.00

> Please note, that the returned value is a string, use with caution.

Answer (score 2):

```
Math.round(num * 100) / 100
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing it:

first:

use **Math.ceil** for round up

for eg:

Math.ceil("your digits");

Also you can use the following

parseFloat("123.456").toFixed(2);

Answer (score 0):

Use **[.toFixed()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp)** function as below.

```
var num = 5.56789;
var n = num.toFixed(2);
// OUTPUT n = 6.57
```

The ***toFixed()*** method converts a number into a string, keeping a specified number of decimals.

Comment: @Jagadeesh - please see above answer and also visit the link .. it will explain you more about .toFixed() function ....Thanks ... Glad to help you :-)

Comment: Its not working inside the jquery syntax. Do we have anything specific to jquery